# Javascript как передать ссылку на HTML элемент в функцию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть таблица, в которой есть кнопка "Удалить" в каждой строки, при нажатии на которую выставляется дата удаления. Теперь я хочу сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы вызывалась функция проверки даты(стоит ли она уже), если да, то кнопку дезактивируем параметром disabled.
Как вызвать правильно вызвать функцию, чтобы передать ссылку на каждый элемент button?
Я делал так, но не получилось:

```
<td>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><script>checkDate(this,${deleteDate})</script>Удалить</button>
</td>
```

И вот так тоже не получается:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onload="checkDate(this,${deleteDate})">Удалить</button>
</td>
```

Есть идеи?

Comment: Лучше всего условие прописать при выводе строк, которые я так понимаю у вас через php выводятся, т.е. у вас есть цикл к примеру где каждая итерация это строка таблицы, при выводе значения в ячейку (тег td) проверяйте на наличие даты и блокируйте вашу кнопку удаления.

Comment: Если хотите использовать js и конкретно jQuery, вам стоит объявить метод `$(document).ready()`, который сработает после загрузки страницы и уже в нем писать условие.

Comment: А зачем что-то вызывать?... Вы как понимаете стоит там удаление уже или нет (где это хранится)?

Comment: @RifmaMan я использую Java, и шаблонизатор jsp

Comment: @InDevX в БД заносится, при нажатии на кнопку Удалить

Comment: @RifmaMan я понимаю, что нужен метод $(document).ready(), но что в него передавать?)

Comment: @h0RNET_ не нужен никакой метод.. Вы когда выводите данные делайте проверку - если с базы запись имеет удаление - добавляйте атрибут disabled (увы, на java не могу показать, не знаком с ним). Тут никакой JS не нужен.

Comment: @h0RNET_ мы оба с InDevX пытаемся вам дать понять что на шаге формирования вывода html (сторона бэкэнда) нужно делать условие а не уже в браузере на стороне фронтенда, однако если вам прям так нужно это сделать, в методе $(document).ready(), вы должны перебрать свои кнопки опять же у вас должны быть даты чтобы можно было в условии отличить ставить атрибут `disabled=""` или нет, достать даты вы можете с атрибута `data-date_deleted` (к примеру) если запишите туда дату, либо аякс запросом запросить список заново у Java и сверяя данные ставить атрибут `disabled=""`, как-то так...

Comment: @RifmaMan 
Спасибо, разобрался, ниже написал ответом на свой вопрос) не знаю о том вы говорили или нет, но такой способ сработал )

Comment: @InDevX разобрался, спасибо)

Comment: @h0RNET_ Именно это мы и имели в виду, условие в выводе )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, может кому будет полезна информация. Средствами jstl можно внедрить атрибут по условию прямо в параметры тега с помощью <c:if> и <c:out>

```
<td>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
      <c:if test="${employee.deleted == true}"> <%--если сотрудник удален--%>
         <c:out value="disabled"></c:out> <%--вставляем атрибут disabled--%>
      </c:if>
   >Удалить</button>
</td>
```